# What is the correct way to ask for a phone call while texting?

Tags: word-usage

The context is: We were texting, then I got tired. What is the natural way to ask for a call instead of continuing texting?

- Hey, do you want to call?
- Do you want to talk on the phone?
- Can we talk on the phone?
- Do you want to call me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You could also try the more assertive method: I'm kind of tired of texting. Let's talk on the phone instead. This takes pressure off of the other person because you have let them know your stated intention and reason for it.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I'm afraid that it might give the pressure on my partner. Do you think so?

Comment: Saying, "Let's talk on the phone instead" creates less pressure. Asking if the other person wants to talk on the phone creates more pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, all of the above are more than acceptable - but of course, the formality of the situation can play a part, as it would in any conversation. For example, if my boss was calling me, I might message back:

> Perhaps it would be easier to talk on the phone?

otherwise, I would simply say:

> Hey, can you call me?
>
> *or*
>
> Hey, can I call you?